# SYNC with master failed: -ERR unknown command 'SYNC'

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I was trying to dump my Redis data that is hosted via AWS.  I can log into the interactive mode via redis-cli, but when I tried dumping the data to an RDB file I received the following error in the title...

user@awshost:~/TaoRedisExtract$ redis-cli -h myawsredis.amazonaws.com --rdb redis.dump.rdb
SYNC with master failed: -ERR unknown command 'SYNC'

I'm not sure if this is a bug, a configuration issue, or known/expected behavior for AWS redis?  I've searched and searched and not found any other reports of users getting this error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [reply of similar question of aws forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=220449&tstart=0)

> From redis version 2.8.22 SYNC has been disabled:
>
> "To maintain enhanced replication performance in Multi-AZ replication groups and for increased cluster stability, non-ElastiCache replicas are no longer supported"

Comment: but you can try [this](http://jimmyislive.tumblr.com/post/107077553355/exporting-data-from-aws-redis-elasticache)